# Interpreting negative beta coefficients

Tags: regression, interpretation

I'm running a negative binomial regression to test the intensity of violent events in a given location. One of my X variables has a negative beta coefficient (BC), however the hypothesis behind that variable is  a 'negative decline in X contributes to a positive chabe in voilence'. My X variable is vegetation cover - so, if there is a decline in vegetation, the hypothesis would posit an increase in violence. I was wondering, because the hypothesis behind that variable is for a negative, rather than positive change in X effecting a postive change in Y, would I interpret a negative BC as supporting the hypotheis or not? Am I right in thinking the regression would quantify the BC through looking at a postive change from the mean? I don't know how to interpret this, unless there is a way for me to change my varibale/ if I need too?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Did you mean to say "negative decline in X", which I read as meaning "an increase in X"? Generally, a negative `X` coefficient means that an increase in `Y` is associated with a decrease in `X` (and vice versa).

Comment: I merged your unregistered account with this one, Stephen, in order to unify the records.